# Context.Entry().GetDatabaseValues() method doesn't copy entity's children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a WPF project with Entity Framework. I used the `Context.Entry().GetDatabaseValues()` method to get original object values for the object being updated. The .GetDatabaseValues() method returns original value with null values for inner objects

As the following :

```
public partial class LabPayments 
{
   public partial class LabAccount
   {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> MaterialID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> LabID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> MaterialDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> LabMaterialPriceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Lab Lab { get; set; }
    public virtual LabMaterial LabMaterial { get; set; }
    public virtual LabMaterialPrice LabMaterialPrice { get; set; }
}
```

The returned virtual object values are null !!

Comment: not sure what you mean by this *The last method returns original value with null values for inner objects*.Also the actual code involved here is not posted. Looks like you use that method on an newly attached entity which does not have any existing (determined via the key) record on database.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> Queries the database for copies of the values of the tracked entity as they currently exist in the database.
>   <sup><sub>*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.getdatabasevalues(v=vs.113).aspx*</sub></sup>

> ```
> using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
> { 
>     var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1); 
>
>     var clonedBlog = context.Entry(blog).GetDatabaseValues().ToObject(); 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the object returned is not the entity and is not being tracked by the context. The returned object also does not have any relationships set to other objects.
>   <sup><sub>*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx*</sub></sup>

---

`GetDatabaseValues` gets the *values* only for the tracked entity, not any navigation properties or collection properties, which are only representations of a relationship/association. Those virtual properties are references to related entity objects and won't be returned with `GetDatabaseValues`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , But Is There Is any way or meythode  To Copy The Object and its  Inner virtual Objects ?

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAbdullah: What are you using the copy for? You might be better off writing your own method to copy what you want to copy. What if the referenced objects have their own referenced objects? What if there are reference loops?