# Why are the details of a row added to an SQL Server table not returned?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version="1.1.2" with stored procedures where the primary key is generated automatically by the SQL DBMS

I thought the code below would return the details of the row I add but it doesn't.

My code is ....

```
            using (DataBaseContext dbInstance = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                Table newTable = new Table()
                {
                    tableName = addTable_TableNameTextBox.Text,
                    tableDescription = addTable_TableDescriptionTextBox.Text,
                    tableLongDescription = addTable_TableLongDescriptionTextBox.Text
                };
                DbInstance.DbTables.Add(newTable);
                DbInstance.SaveChanges();
                DbInstance.Entry(newTable).GetDatabaseValues();
                // The rows are added by the instructions above but GetDatabaseValues() doesn't retrieve the data that was added (I thought it would).
                // The row is being added OK and I can retrieve it using the following instruction (when I explicitly specify the key). 
                NewTable = dbInstance.DbTables.Find(97);
            }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using title-case for variable names makes your code more confusing to read.  .Net naming conventions for C# dictate that variable names should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Thanks Amy.  I'm struggling to learn how to play this game.  Your feedback most appreciated.

Comment: This question already have an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831168/context-entry-getdatabasevalues-method-doesnt-copy-entitys-children

Comment: As I see it you aren't adding a row to a SQL Server table, instead you're adding a table to a SQL Server database.  The question you linked to is also interesting, as you don't seem to be following the accepted answer, but are instead following another answer that handles a very specific case.  In that answer the GetDatabaseValues doesn't return the id of the object you just added, instead you will need to use "int id = myNewObject.Id;".

Comment: ...or to be more specific you would use int i = NewTable.Id;  What version of Visual Studio are you using, if it's a version with ReSharper built in then you should be able to fix your naming conventions with a few clicks :D

Comment: Sounds like entity property configuration issue. With proper configuration EF Core should automatically gather for you the information needed after `SaveChanges` without a need of explicit method call. Also rather than using `GetDatabaseValues` which returns `PropertyValues` instance which you are ignoring, you can use `Reload` method instead.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  Can you tell me how I can verify my EF Core configuration is correct?  Also do you mean  I tried  DbInstance.Entry(newTable).Reload() without success - is that syntax correct?

Comment: What exactly does the stored procedure do and how is it triggered? What is the DBMS? Also, you use the tag [entity-framework-6] but you're actually using ef-core.

Comment: Thanks Gert.  The stored procedure adds a row of data to the table.  It is triggered by DbInstance.DbTables.Add(newTable) and it works.  The DBMS is MS SQL server.  ef-core didn't come up when I entered entity - sorry.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK ef-core doesn't support CUD mapping to stored procedures [yet](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap), so I don't know how `Add` could trigger this sproc unless it's triggered by a database on-insert trigger. In the latter case, the returned `SCOPE_IDENTITY` value may be affected by the sproc, so `newTable` won't have the correct Id value set (or none at all).

Comment: you must be give primary key in your table than find function working in EF

Comment: Gert,   It was my intention to use EF Core and I installed that from NuGet.  However, the Packages.config file tells me ...
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net452" />
I'm not sure how to interpret that.
Have I entangled EF version=6.1.3 and EF-Core  version=1.1.2?
Nevertheless Add triggers the stored procedure which is visible via the "Stored procedures mapping" window of the .edmx Diagram.
Rows add fine but the added details don't echo back. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd remove the ef-core package since you're clearly using ef6. So now again, what does the (insert) stored procedure do? It should return and Id value for EF to pick it up after saving the entity. Maybe you should show its code.

Comment: Gert, I've rebuilt the solution using EF6 and now am trying to create a stored procedure that returns all the added row columns as OUTPUT parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh the context, after which your `newTable` variable will have your details (I'm assuming other properties of the table).

```
using (DataBaseContext dbInstance = new DataBaseContext())
{
    Table newTable = new Table()
    {
        tableName = addTable_TableNameTextBox.Text,
        tableDescription = addTable_TableDescriptionTextBox.Text,
        tableLongDescription = addTable_TableLongDescriptionTextBox.Text
    };
    DbInstance.DbTables.Add(newTable);
    DbInstance.SaveChanges();

    // Refresh the context
    DbInstance.Entry(newTable).Reload();       
}
```

Comment: Ivan, Thanks for clarifying that.  I still can't get it to work but will spend time tomorrow.  Grateful for your help.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Both dbInstance.Entry(newTable).Reload(); and dbInstance.Entry(newRiskArea).GetDatabaseValues(); return the details of the added row BUT only if you are using the EF default insert function.
It wasn't working for me because I was trying to insert the new row using a stored procedure. The stored procedure seems to suppress the Reload() and GetDatabaseValues() methods; Thanks for your help.  Now I need to learn how to return details of the added row using a stored procedure with OUTPUT parameters.